# Selecting Multiple RadioButtons

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a windows form in C# where a user must select more than one `RadioButton`, however only 1 `RadioButton` can be selected.

I provide an image to illustrate my problem

[image]

and this is my code:

```
if (radioButton3.Checked == true)
{
     if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
     {
          NpgsqlCommand cmd10 = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO visual_acuity (eid, corrected, is_left_eye, value) VALUES (@eid, @corrected, @is_left_eye, @value)", conn);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox17.Text);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_left_eye", radioButton2.Checked);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrected", radioButton4.Checked);
          cmd10.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
     {
          NpgsqlCommand cmd11 = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO visual_acuity (eid, corrected, is_left_eye, value) VALUES (@eid, @corrected, @is_left_eye, @value)", conn);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox17.Text);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_left_eye", radioButton2.Checked);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrected", radioButton4.Checked);
          cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
else
{
     if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
     {
          NpgsqlCommand cmd10 = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO visual_acuity (eid, corrected, is_left_eye, value) VALUES (@eid, @corrected, @is_left_eye, @value)", conn);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox17.Text);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_left_eye", radioButton2.Checked);
          cmd10.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrected", radioButton4.Checked);
          cmd10.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
     {
          NpgsqlCommand cmd11 = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO visual_acuity (eid, corrected, is_left_eye, value) VALUES (@eid, @corrected, @is_left_eye, @value)", conn);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", textBox17.Text);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@is_left_eye", radioButton2.Checked);
          cmd11.Parameters.AddWithValue("@corrected", radioButton4.Checked);
          cmd11.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

If you have any suggestions, please feel free to comment. it would be a big help. thanks!

Comment: make the corrected vision into a checkbox

Comment: I think you should use checkbox instead of radio in that scenario.

Comment: Does [How to check multiple radio buttons at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74998532/5438626) help answer your question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Radio buttons got their name from the station buttons on a car radio, where only one station can be selected at a time. And that is the purpose of radio button controls.

Only one button in a group can be selected. Also consider that experienced users instantly know only one option can be selected just by looking at them because they behave consistently across applications. So changing the way radio buttons work would be confusing to users.

If you want more than one selected at a time, then you do not want a radio button. Use checkboxes instead.

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention. im using WinForms

Comment: Worth to note is that Radio buttons can cause problems in WPF templates. If you create RadioButtons with GroupName property, all the buttons will be members of the same group. That leads to only one radio button being selectable. We used to have a StackPanel template with RadioButtons and unintentionally multiple StackPanels shared only 1 selectable button. That would be counter-intuitive for the clients and hard to notice in big code base. Same problem led me here.

Answer (score 7):

You have to put RadioButtons into Panels or GroupBoxes.

Then you can select them independently in each such group.

Answer (score 2):

if user must select just one of (Left and right) use checkbox for corrected version