# How to check multiple radio buttons at once

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to coding, and I am currently taking a course. I am trying to make a color mixer where you select two radio buttons from two different categories. But when I run the program, I can only select one radio button at a time.
Here is the code I am using:

```
private void btnMix_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radRedFirst.Checked && radRedSecond.Checked)
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    else if (radBlueFirst.Checked && radBlueSecond.Checked)
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    else if (radYellowFirst.Checked && radYellowSecond.Checked)
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    else if ((radRedFirst.Checked && radBlueSecond.Checked) ||
            (radBlueFirst.Checked && radRedSecond.Checked))
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
    else if ((radRedFirst.Checked && radYellowSecond.Checked) ||
            (radYellowFirst.Checked && radRedSecond.Checked))
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
    else if ((radBlueFirst.Checked && radYellowSecond.Checked) ||
        (radYellowFirst.Checked && radBlueSecond.Checked))
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
}
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

I have tried using Panel, but I don't really understand how they work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting Multiple RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31955548/selecting-multiple-radiobuttons)

Comment: You should have different value of ```name``` attribute for different groups of radio buttons

Comment: "I am trying to make a color mixer where you select two radio buttons from two different categories." Add a `GroupBox` (from the ToolBox) for each category and change the Text property to the name of that category. Now add the RadioButtons for each category into their respective groupboxes. Only one RadioButton from each GroupBox will be allowed to be selected at once.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I want to go on record as agreeing with what you're saying but since the question title is _how to check multiple radio buttons at once_ I say we have a little [fun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74998532/5438626) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about Winforms is that you can almost always inherit a standard control to make a custom version with the functionality you want. The trick is to try and do it in a way that doesn't upend the expected behavior to the point that your user is frustrated when the UI doesn't match their **mental model**<sup>1</sup> of how it should work.

That said, if you're *sure* you want to do this I won't stand in your way but must "insist" that the **[Control]** modifier key be held for the click in keeping with the convention for accessing multiselection when it's available.

With that disclaimer, this `RadioButtonMulti` class can be swapped out in your designer file.

[image: multiselect] *Control + Click to multiselect.*

---

Looking at the default behavior of a RadioButton as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-group-windows-forms-radiobutton-controls-to-function-as-a-set).

> You group radio buttons by drawing them inside a container such as a Panel control, a GroupBox control, or a form. All radio buttons that are added directly to a form become one group.

This tells us what exactly what we need to do! *We need to temporarily make the clicked button "think" that it doesn't belong to any group.*  Here's one way that I [tested](https://github.com/IVSoftware/radio-button-mutiselect.git) that removes the control from its Parent.Controls collection while it toggles the `Checked` state.

```
class RadioButtonMulti : RadioButton
{
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        if(ModifierKeys.Equals(Keys.Control))
        {
            var parentB4 = Parent;
            try
            {
                parentB4.Controls.Remove(this);
                Checked = !Checked;
            }
            finally
            {
                parentB4.Controls.Add(this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var others =
                Parent.Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .Where(_ => _ is RadioButtonMulti)
                .Where(_ => !ReferenceEquals(_, this));
            foreach (RadioButtonMulti other in others)
            {
                other.Checked = false;
            }
            base.OnMouseDown(mevent);
        }
    }
```

Display selection in main form title bar for demonstration purposes only.

```
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
        if(Form.ActiveForm != null)
        {
            var group =
                Parent.Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .Where(_ => _ is RadioButtonMulti)
                .Where(_ => ((RadioButtonMulti)_).Checked);
            Form.ActiveForm.Text = string.Join(", ", group.Select(_ => _.Text));
        }
    }
}
```

---

1. See also [Mental Models and Computer Models](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5150/2019sp/slides/9-usability.pdf) pp. 11-12.

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/radio-button-mutiselect.git) this sample.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler as, e.g., `if (ModifierKeys.Equals(Keys.Control)) AutoCheck = false;
else Parent!.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonMulti>().Select(_=>_.AutoCheck = true).ToList(); Checked = !Checked;`? -- Your version should work anyway, so... -- The call to `base` is inside the `else` condition block

Comment: Yes, I thought so, and tried it first after reading your first comments on the question but I couldn't get it to work when tested which left me perplexed.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple radio buttons are not supposed to be selected. Only one is supposed to be selected.

You should look at using checkboxes instead, as this will resolve your issue. :)

Comment: Multiple RadioButtons are *supported*. You usually group RadioButtons with different roles in different Containers, to enforce single selection. But you can enable multiple selection, by setting the `AutoCheck` Property to `false`. Should you use CheckBoxes in this case, instead of RadioButtons? Probably, but not mandatory or unsupported

Comment: @Jimi I'm concerned. I believe that setting `AutoCheck` to `false` will only serve to make the button do "nothing at all" when you click it. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @IVSoftware It means that the RadioButton is not automatically checked when clicked, which affects how [PerformAutoUpdates](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/RadioButton.cs,494) behaves. When you set this Property to `false`, setting the `Checked` Property in code doesn't affect other RadioButtons within the same Parent Container. You can handle, e.g., the `Click` event to change their state (so you have RadioButtons that behave almost as CheckBoxes. Counter-intuitive? Maybe)

Comment: @Jimi ok when you put it that way [can confirm](https://github.com/IVSoftware/radio-button-autocheck-false.git). And yes, "checkboxes that look like radio buttons" which is sinister and why my full answer insists on [Control] + Click as a compromise. Only problem is that I couldn't get it to work changing `AutoCheck` _dynamically_ inline as an impl (probably because of how the messaging works) so I ended up doing it the way I'm doing it.